# TFS Web Access — How to add the Burndown chart to team favorites?

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

How can I add the Current Sprint iteration and burn-down chart to the landing page for TFS Web Access?  I am able to pull in the build and backlog queries into "team favorites", but can not seem to find how to add current sprint info and the Work Burn-down chart like I've seen elsewhere.

[image: TFS web-access screenshot]

Comment: Your post is tagged TFS 2010, but I'm assuming you mean TFS 2012?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not added via Team Favorites.  It will automatically show up if your user account is setup with "Full" Access vs the default Standard access (you will also get the links to View Backlog and View Board to access the Agile Planning functionality).

[image: TFSWA Home Page]

You can configure the user access levels by going to the settings page (gear icon in upper-right), then navigating to the root Control Panel (using the breadcrumbs in upper left), then choosing Access Levels Tab.

[image: TFSWA Access Levels]

Comment: Just for additional information: My burndown chart disappeared when some iterations where unchecked by mistake.